# Validating user supplied input

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I was assigned a task to fix the SQL injection flaw reported by a code analysis tool. I am not the original author of the code. I am fairly knowledgeable with SQL.

```
 public int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
 {
     using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(query, parameters))
     {
         int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         log.Debug("rows affected: {0}", rowsAffected);
         return rowsAffected;
     }
 }
```

and the tool has reported the injection flaw at the line number 3. The `ExecuteNonQuery` is being called from so many places.

Here is one such sample:

```
public void AddDataFrom(IWorkflowStepExecutionStorage storage, bool inverseSourceAndTargetSide)
{
    WorkflowStepExecutionStorage storageImpl = storage as WorkflowStepExecutionStorage;
    if (storageImpl == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    const string queryTemplate =
        @"insert into [$mappingDictionaryTable](sourceObjectId, sourceObject, targetObjectId, targetObject, linkedObjectTypesPairId)
          select sourceTable.objectId, sourceTable.systemEntry, targetTable.objectId, targetTable.systemEntry, @linkedObjectTypesPairId from
            [$mappingTable] mt
            inner join [$sourceImportStorageTable] sourceTable on mt.$sourceIdColumn = sourceTable.id
            inner join [$targetImportStorageTable] targetTable on mt.$targetIdColumn = targetTable.id
        ";
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(queryTemplate);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$mappingDictionaryTable", this.mappingDictionaryTable.TableName);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$mappingTable", storageImpl.MappedTable.TableName);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$sourceImportStorageTable", inverseSourceAndTargetSide ?
        (storageImpl.TargetImportStorage as ImportExecutionStorage).ImportTable.TableName :
        (storageImpl.SourceImportStorage as ImportExecutionStorage).ImportTable.TableName);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$targetImportStorageTable", inverseSourceAndTargetSide ?
        (storageImpl.SourceImportStorage as ImportExecutionStorage).ImportTable.TableName :
        (storageImpl.TargetImportStorage as ImportExecutionStorage).ImportTable.TableName);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$sourceIdColumn", inverseSourceAndTargetSide ? MappedTable.TargetIdColumn.Name : MappedTable.SourceIdColumn.Name);
    queryBuilder.AddParameter("$targetIdColumn", inverseSourceAndTargetSide ? MappedTable.SourceIdColumn.Name : MappedTable.TargetIdColumn.Name);

    string query = queryBuilder.GetParametrizedQuery();
    SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new[] { new SqlParameter("@linkedObjectTypesPairId", storageImpl.RunConfiguration.LinkedTypesPairConfiguration.Id) };

    using (IQcDbConnection dbConnection = this.connectionProvider.CreateDbConnection())
    {
        dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(query, sqlParams);
    }
}
```

Here is the `CreateCommand` code:

```
private SqlCommand CreateCommand(string commandText, SqlParameter[] parameters)
 {
     SqlCommand retVal = this.connection.CreateCommand();
     retVal.CommandText = commandText;
     retVal.CommandTimeout = this.commandsTimeout;
     retVal.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
     return retVal;
}
```

Is there any injection risk in this code? If yes, how do I recognize it?

Comment: Just to be sure: are you asking about understanding code instead of a review and did or didn't you write the code yourself?

Comment: I have understood the code. But I am asking about SLQ injection risk and fixing it.

Comment: The important code is in `QueryBuilder` and `CreateCommand` but it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only so much a code analysis tool can see.

> ```
> using (SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(query, parameters))
> ```

You're using a parameterized `SqlCommand`, and *given the example* you *appear to* have everything under your own control, strongly typed and all.

Depends *who* is calling this `ExecuteNonQuery` method, and where `query` is coming from.

It appears the `query` is coming from a `QueryBuilder`, out of a *QueryTemplate*.

The thing is, this `QueryBuilder` has been given the ability to perform replacement of "tokens" in the SQL command string, and it seems to be taking in a `string` for the replacement - if I were a code analysis tool, I'd raise a flag right there.

I don't see any apparent specific problem with the example usage you've supplied. But how the API is used is the responsibility of the programmer using it, and the API takes a SQL command string, *and actually sends another to the server*. The API could easily be misused to misplace these "tokens" and pass a user-supplied value as the replacement value, and bingo, you have SQL injection happening.

In other words, I think there *is* a *potential* SQL injection issue with the API, *if it's misused*. But if it's used everywhere the way you've shown, in my opinion you can put that warning onto the "false positives" pile.

Using an Object Relational Mapper, or any *current technology* for that matter (Entity Framework comes to mind), could significantly reduce all that boilerplate - and risk of misuse. But no API is shielded from carelessness.

---

I can't help but mention this one:

```
SqlCommand retVal = this.connection.CreateCommand();
```

`retVal` reads like VBA code from 1998. You're using readable identifiers everywhere else; would `returnValue` kill anyone? Personally I use `result` all the time. I can live with `params`, but seeing `retVal` in my code base would automatically trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd> and a new name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well I noted your points. I also discussed the same with my superior. What my Superior is saying is to add validation in the AddDataFrom method to validate the query. But what I think is, adding validation in that method wont fix the flaw reported by tool. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using, and I've never used such a code inspection tool (R# suffices for my needs) - I don't know how such a tool figures out the flaws, but I don't think it would, indeed. IMHO whatever validation you add *might* work, but is just lipstick on a pig: I believe the key point is that the SQL command string is being tampered with *as a feature*, when the idea of a parameterized query is to avoid replacements and concatenations.